NextJS - Dynamic Route overriding static one
I have a /music route in WP and a static /music page on my NextJS.
For now, I need to keep both as I will keep the two versions (full WP and headless) of the website in parallel.
According to documentation, static routes should override dynamic ones, but the opposite is happening. When I build the website, the generated page contains the content of the WP page, not the one in my static route (music/page.tsx).
Any idea what could be happening?
I am using the 'standalone' export, but the issue was happening on 'export' as well.
I expect the static route to overide the dynamic one.
